# Is there a good repository of IE 6 considerations?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-6

I've been lucky to develop websites for the past 3 years for companies that don't need to support IE 6 in any way.

I've just accepted a development job with a company that works  **exclusively** with IE 6 customers in the financial field. These people may be hemmed in by corporate IT departments or haven't upgraded, or whatever the reason is, we have to support IE 6 (and JUST IE 6).

I have no background in supporting this browser and I used to happily skip over SO questions that dealt with IE `lte` selectors and all of that. But now that it's going to pay the bills, I want to know as mch as I can about the CSS selectors that work/don't work, how JS may be quirky, and anything else that may help me catch up in the new job.

Is there a good respository of the "quirks" that make up the lovable IE 6 experience, or is it spread piecemeal across the 'tubes?

Comment: I sincerely hope that some other parts of the job make up for having to target IE6 exclusively ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At [hasLayout](http://haslayout.net/css/) is an excellent overview of all known IE CSS bugs, most of them complete with solutions. This site is imo better overviewable, a real bug repository. All is summarized in short instead of spread over 100s pages like [Quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org), which in turn is however excellent as a *general reference*.

Answer (score 11):

> Is there a good respository of the "quirks" that make up the lovable IE 6 experience

[**quirksmode.org**](http://www.quirksmode.org) is an excellent resource for browser compatibility questions. It has great, nicely designed compatibility tables that give you almost everything you need to know. Be sure to take a look.

Answer (score 3):

My clients use IE6.  The repositories listed above may mention these, but nevertheless I write them here.

- If you use https, [avoid mixed content messages](http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/bugs.asp) by avoiding javascript:void(0) and similar constructs.
- If you use https, [avoid mixed content messages](http://ajaxian.com/archives/ie-frame-bug) by ensuring all iframes have a valid src attribute.
- Find a copy of [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Script_Debugger) and learn to love it.  It stinks, but it seems to be the only game in town.
- Ask your company to let you develop using FF and FireBug (I did), develop using these, and **test very often** in IE6.
- I use the following URL to dump the DOM: 
  `javascript:'<xmp>%20+%20window.document.body.outerHTML%20+%20</xmp>'`

Answer (score 2):

[Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/) is an invaluable source of information for this sort of thing.

In particular, take a look at the [compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html).

Answer (score 2):

"[QuirksMode.org](http://quirksmode.org/) is the prime source for browser compatibility information on the Internet." Specifically, to your question visit the [CSS2](http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) page there, and look at the IE6 column on the table.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice article about the [9 most common IE bugs and how to fix them](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them/).

Answer (score 1):

Good suggestions... a couple of things that might help:

- "Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition" is much better than the old "Microsoft Script Debugger": http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/
- There's also Firebug Lite: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite
- A compatibility library for browsers that lack full support for JavaScript 1.6: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Gadget-JSL.js
- MSDN will help too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx